# Publishing of orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to do a re-publish of orbeon forms automatically? (ie Forms that have been created with Form Builder and which have been saved and deployed/published before).

Actually we are upgrading from Orbeon 3.9 to Orbeon 4.6, and currently we have lots of orbeon forms in our 3.9 environment. since its very difficult to publish the forms one by one after upgrade to 4.6, it will be good if i can find an easy way to republish all the existing forms.

I found something here at https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Home-Page
When I tried this, I didn't get any error but the forms were not actually published. and I got error when I opened a new instance of any existing forms.

Appreciate if any one can help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the orbeon log for errors? If orbeon is running in production mode there may be an error that is not displayed to the user.

I haven't gone through an upgrade myself, but it's possible that you need to upgrade your form definitions. Orbeon 4.6 includes a feature to do this in bulk on the Form Runner Home Page. See the [4.6 blog post](http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/06/orbeon-forms-46.html).

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, see [the Run Modes documenation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/run-modes) for more info on production and dev modes.

Comment: I did the same as described in  4.6 blog post ( selected forms and clicked on 'Upgrade form definitions' from form runner home page ), but still am not able to open any new instance or edit old form instance. I checked error log , there i can find "ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - error caught {controller: "oxf:/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/appName/formName/edit/195caf26c38c9934cea465e7e864c285"}

Comment: I've noticed that the stack traces are quite long in Orbeon and there are usually several of them for one error. There may be more information about why this error occurred.